# unique default state/class to react toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below, except currently it's setting the *minimize* class as default. Toggling works fine, I just would like a unique *default class* to be show at first before any click has happened. After a click, it would then go between maximize and minimize classes as it does now.

If I could keep the below functionality, and just prevent maximize or minimize classes from being added automatically, this should solve the issue, however anytime I try to remove it breaks.

```
class ToggleIt extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       expandedTray: false,
     }
     this.toggleExpandedTray = this.toggleExpandedTray.bind(this);
   }
   toggleExpandedTray() {
     this.setState({ expandedTray: !this.state.expandedTray, });
   }
   render() {
     return (
         <div
           className={`something--isi-tray ${this.state.expandedTray ? 'expanded-tray' : 'minimize-tray'}`}
           onClick={this.toggleExpandedTray}
         >
           <div className="something--isi-tray__content">
               <h3>{this.props.mainHeadingTitle}</h3>
            <div
                  data-rte-editelement
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
               __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(this.props.isiContent)
            }}
            />
           </div>
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Toggling works fine, I just would like a unique default class to be
> show at first before any click has happened.

If I correctly understood you could set `null` as initial value in state, and then

```
this.state.expandedTray === null ? "some-class" : this.state.expandedTray ? 'expanded-tray' : 'minimize-tray'
```

Comment: yep, that is what im trying to do

Comment: will try it now

Comment: This is still setting it to minimize class by default for some reason, as before

Comment: @fredrandall did you assign null in constructor instead of false?